# Having trouble accessing the properties of the objects in my array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I currently have this function that populates an array with objects with 2 properties, color and angle.

```
function populateArray() {
  let lines = [];
  let numOfLines = 200;
  let colorArray = [
    '#0f41ff',
    '#f5680e',
    '#9536ac',
    '#d8ad00',
    '#bd58a4',
    '#f8c586',
    '#406309',
    '#ed0f00',
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++) {
    let randomColorNumber = getRandomInt(colorArray.length);
    let randomColor = colorArray[randomColorNumber];
    let randomAngle = getRandomFloat(10, 20);
    if (i % 2 === 1) {
      randomAngle = randomAngle * -1;
    }
    lines.push([{ color: randomColor, angle: randomAngle }]);
  }
  return lines;
```

That is working just fine, and when I `console.log(lines)` I get the array of objects perfectly.

I can even do `console.log(lines[0])`, and that works fine. It returns something like this: `{color: "#f5680e", angle: -13.180879351807855}`.

But, when I try to access the properties of an index, it returns undefined.  For example, `console.log(lines[0].color)` returns undefined.

This is my problem, I need to access these values, but I can't.  It's weird though, as I can access the whole object itself, and there is only one function that populates my array, and no asynchronous calls are being made.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `lines.push([{ color: randomColor, angle: randomAngle }])` This always pushes an array with a single element in it to `lines`. Remove the `[` and `]` there. (Or log `lines[0][0].color`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push object: lines.push(**{...}**); not array lines.push(**[...]**);

```
lines.push({ color: randomColor, angle: randomAngle });
```

or log lines[0]**[0]**.color